# The "ret" instruction isn't returning to the correct address

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

I believe that when I call "WriteFile", it doesn't clean the stack, but I think that's highly unlikely, so I guess I'm using the function wrong. I've looked everywhere but I can't find an answer as to what I'm doing wrong. I've only included a small snippet of my assembly as that's where I narrowed the problem down to.

```
segment .text
    global main
    extern GetStdHandle
    extern WriteFile
    extern ReadConsoleA
    extern Sleep
    extern ExitProcess

write:  mov rcx, -11    ; WRITE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax
    
    lea r9, [rbp-32]
    push 0
    call WriteFile
    ret

main:   push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    mov rdx, msg
    mov r8, msg_len
    call write

    mov rcx, -10    ; READ
    call GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax

    mov rdx, buffer
    mov r8, 64
    lea r9, [rbp-8]
    push 0
    call ReadConsoleA
```

When I removed this part of the code, the program did return to the correct address as I was able to input.

```
    lea r9, [rbp-32]
    push 0
    call WriteFile
```

Comment: You forgot to set up the shadow space in `write`. Also in 64 bit mode the caller removes the arguments.

Comment: A debugger will show you what's going on, that RSP before and after the call are the same.  If you didn't already know about shadow space, you might not know why the function was overwriting stuff above its stack args, but that is indeed what happens.  Use a debugger and read MS's calling convention docs.

Comment: PS: `main` does try to set up a shadow space with `sub rsp, 32` but then it uses `push 0` which again messes it up. The 5th argument goes on top of the shadow space.

Comment: As an example how to invoke Windows 64bit function look at the expansion of macro [WinABI](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winabi.htm#WinABI) in the paragraph **Example ; Fast Version**.